# Regex: match URLs except some?

Tags: regex

I would like to match all URLs, except some. I have the regex below. This excludes URLs that end with `.html`, but I also want to exclude URLs that have (somewhere) 'sub-cat' or 'sub-cat2' in it.
This is however not working currently. What is going wrong? Thanks!

```
/webshop/category/.*+$(?<!\.html|sub-cat|sub-cat2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a negative lookahead condition with alternations:

```sh
^(?!.*(sub-cat|sub-cat2|\.html$).*/webshop/category/.+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJXyQq/1)

`(?!.*(sub-cat|sub-cat2|\.html$)` will fail your match if URL ends with `.html` or if it has `sub-cat` or `sub-cat2` anywhere.